# External WD Drive showing read only

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk

I have WD External SSD Drive and macOS Catalina. The drive is formatted in `ExFAT`

Initially, I used my external drive 2-3 times and it was working fine. Suddenly today I am not able to write anything in my Drive as its showing Read-Only.

output from `mount`

```
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/MUKESH (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

I have tried running following command but it did not work.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Volumes/MUKESH
```

Here is what I see in disk utility
[image]

In Get-Info section I see this.

[image]

Comment: Can you drop down the Sharing and Permissions and add yourself back in as R/W?  IT could also be objecting to being pulled rather than eject - check disk utility and run repair on it.

Comment: Did that, but still, it's not working.

Comment: Both of them or one of them?

Comment: Is your computer a personal machine, or a centrally managed machine from an employer?  There is an IT management policy that can lock out writes to external storage for security reasons

Comment: @vykor My machine is my office machine, I am not sure if the software which was installed is blocking it. How do I check it? I do not have another mac machine.

Comment: @Mukesh Yadav the easiest way to check is if you insert other external storage devices, and they're all set to read-only.  If that's the case, this is likely a MDM policy that is pushed by your IT organization (no additional software required - they just have to check a box on their end).  You'll want to ask IT to remove the policy for you in that case.

Comment: Thank you @vykor I do not have another device. Will check with my office IT guy.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, go into Disk Utility (like you are), and use First Aid on the partition in question.  Depending on the size of your drive, it will take a while, but when it should restore write capability to your disk.

Source: I did the same thing when my MyBook 2TB was randomly showing up as read-only.

Comment: I had tried this option. But apparently, it did not work for me.

Comment: I think that you must assume that you have a bad drive, and immediately make a backup of it (although my experience was on Mojave, not Catalina)

Comment: I tried it in ubuntu machine and it works there.

Comment: If I were you, if Ubuntu has any disk checking tools I'd use those on the drive just in case